# como asigno el objectid a un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

estoy haciendo un foreach de genres que es un array de objectsid que resibo desde req.body, cada elemento que obtengo de ciclo foreach se busca en la coleccion Genres y si existe se agrega a newMovie.genres que es un array que contendra los objectid de los generos que posteriormente seran poblados, pero no logro agregar el object id

el genre si existe, ya lo comprobe. pero no logro agregarlo a newMovie.genres

ya intente haciendo un push, concat, pero no logro hacerlo, como puedo solucionar esto

Este es el codigo de el controlador

```
import Movie, { IMovie } from './movieModel'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import Joi from 'joi'
import { IParams, IQuery, IBody } from '../../custom'
import { response } from '../../lib/jsonResponse'
import Genre from '../genre/genreModel'

export const newMovie = async (req: Request<IParams, {}, IBody, IQuery>, res: Response) => {
  // transfor body to json
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body.movie_data)

  // // validacion de datos
  const { value, error } = Joi.object({
    budget: Joi.number().min(0),
    genres: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).min(1),
    homepage: Joi.string().uri().required().lowercase(),
    original_language: Joi.string().required().lowercase(),
    original_title: Joi.string().required().lowercase(),
    overview: Joi.string().required().lowercase(),
    popularity: Joi.number(),
    production_companies: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).min(1),
    production_countries: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
      iso_3166_1: Joi.string().required(),
      name: Joi.string().required()
    }).min(1)),
    release_date: Joi.string(),
    revenue: Joi.number(),
    runtime: Joi.number(),
    tagline: Joi.string(),
    title: Joi.string(),
    vote_average: Joi.number(),
    vote_count: Joi.number()
  }).validate(body, { abortEarly: false })
  if (error) {
    return response(18, error.message, res)
  }

  const {
    budget,
    genres,
    homepage,
    original_language,
    original_title,
    overview,
    popularity,
    production_countries,
    release_date,
    revenue,
    runtime,
    tagline,
    title,
    vote_average,
    vote_count
  } = value as IMovie

  // new movie
  const newMovie = new Movie({
    budget,
    homepage,
    original_language,
    original_title,
    overview,
    popularity,
    production_countries,
    release_date,
    revenue,
    runtime,
    tagline,
    title,
    vote_average,
    vote_count
  })

  genres.forEach(async (element) => {
    const genre = await Genre.findById(element)
    newMovie.genres.push(genre?._id)
  })

  return res.json(newMovie)
}
```

y este es el modelo de Movie

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'
import { ICompanie } from '../companie/companieModel'
import { IGenre } from '../genre/genreModel'

export interface IMovie {
  backdrop_path: string
  budget: number
  gallery: Array<string>
  genres: Array<string>,
  homepage: string,
  original_language: string,
  original_title: string,
  overview: string,
  popularity: number,
  poster_path: string,
  production_companies: Array<ICompanie>,
  production_countries: Array<{
    iso_3166_1: string,
    name: string
  }>,
  release_date: string,
  revenue: number,
  runtime: number,
  tagline: string,
  title: string,
  vote_average: number,
  vote_count: number
}

const movieSchema = new Schema<IMovie>({
  backdrop_path: String,
  budget: Number,
  gallery: [{
    type: String
  }],
  genres: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genero'
  }],
  homepage: String,
  original_language: String,
  original_title: String,
  overview: String,
  popularity: Number,
  poster_path: String,
  production_companies: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
  }],
  production_countries: [{
    _id: false,
    iso_3166_1: String,
    name: String
  }],
  release_date: String,
  revenue: Number,
  runtime: Number,
  tagline: String,
  title: String,
  vote_average: Number,
  vote_count: Number
})

export default model<IMovie>('Movie', movieSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

el objeto **newMovie** esta inicializado excepto por newMovie.genres, puedes crear una variable `let genresTemp = []` y luego haces push a `genresTemp.push(element)`, finalmente asignas `newMovie.genres = genresTemp` o inicializas en el objecto al crear newMovie y recorres como lo haces ahora.

```
const newMovie = new Movie({
  genre: [],
  budget,
  homepage,
  original_language,
  original_title,
  overview,
  popularity,
  production_countries,
  release_date,
  revenue,
  runtime,
  tagline,
  title,
  vote_average,
  vote_count
})
```

Te recomiendo condicionar la inserción dentro del foreach ya que si no encuentra nada estarás insertando un `NULL` a genres.